# Make selection in a textarea always visible?

Tags: html, css, textarea, textselection

I've noticed that the selection in an HTML textarea (say) will not show once that textarea loses focus. Can this be fixed?

I know about CSS :active, but I guess I'd like an :inactive or something, to do :inactive::selection and for all browsers to obey it.

And the caret, aka insertion point, would be nice too, of course.